# Regex to validate Nigerian phone numbers using PHP's preg_match_all()

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I need a regex to match numbers in the following formats:

```
0000 000 0000
01 000 0000
+234 1 000 0000
0000-000-0000
00000000000
234 000 000 0000
234(000)000-0000
234(000)000 0000
+234(000)000 0000
+234(000) 000 0000
+234(000)000-0000
2340000000000
+2340000000000
```

What I already tried:
`$pattern = '/^234[0-9]{11}/';`

But it only matches:
`23400000000000`

Still a regex newbie. Expression should be fully compatible with PHP 8 PCRE and `preg_match_all()`. Would appreciate an explanation of the expression as well.

Comment: Since I can't answer this --  You were close:  `/234[0-9]*?.*/`  [REGEX](https://regex101.com/r/qDT5Ng/1/)

Comment: And if you needed the `+` in front .. You just  `/.*234[0-9]*?.*/`

Comment: UPDATED if you need `+`   --  `/^(\+)?234[0-9]*?.*/`

Comment: Doesn't work on my end @Zak

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/1099Nr/1  --  That's the basic REGEX ..  If it doesn't work, you aren't setting it up right.

Comment: Also you may need the `global` and `multiline` flags:  `/^(\+)?234[0-9]*?.*/gm`

Comment: Thanks a lot, but still doesnt match `0000-000-0000, 00000000000, 0000 000 0000, 01 000 0000`. You're almost there... @Zak

Comment: Hi @Zak, any idea on how to make it match the remaining characters?

Answer (score 0):

Remove duplicated questions, please.
You can use `reg | reg` as `or` operator. Probably last section can be combined with first, but now it is clear what is going on:

```
(^(\+)?234[\( ]?[0-9]{3}\)? ?[0-9]{3}[\- ]?[0-9]{4})|(^[0-9]{4}[\- ]?[0-9]{3}[\- ]?[0-9]{4})|(^01 ?[0-9]{3} ?[0-9]{4})|(^\+234 1 [0-9]{3} [0-9]{4})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is will do what you are looking for ..  If you go to [THIS SITE, TO SEE DEMO AND EXPLAIATION](https://regex101.com/r/b2Nt8U/1), you can walk through the right column to see HOW it works.  Given you are asking so many questions about regex, I might suggest making a concerted effort to learn the way it works.

```
/^(\+)?(234|0)[0-9]*?.*/
```